# How to make column height shrink to it's content?

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can I make bootstrap column height shrink to its content, It was the default before but it has changed now, parallel columns are all the same size by default?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-sm" style="background-color: blue">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm" style="background-color: red">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent faucibus odio a mauris congue, eu consequat sapien condimentum. Vestibulum sollicitudin tellus a enim porttitor, quis euismod lectus pharetra. Praesent lacinia eget lorem at molestie. Praesent et mauris vitae lorem porta pretium. Aenean ac dictum justo. Integer sodales eros in libero fringilla venenatis. Curabitur convallis semper vehicula. Sed fermentum tempor arcu dapibus facilisis. Etiam ornare orci ullamcorper ipsum tristique aliquet. Quisque tellus felis, aliquam sed sapien vitae, ultrices auctor elit.

Donec commodo at nisi blandit pretium. Duis ornare metus eu felis suscipit, in fringilla dolor aliquet. Sed eleifend consectetur nibh eu.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm" style="background-color: yellow">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the height of the blue and yellow column to fit to the height of their content and not spread all the way to fit the red one's sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add align-items-start to the row containing the columns.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-1  col-sm" style="background-color: blue">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-sm" style="background-color: red">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent faucibus odio a mauris congue, eu consequat sapien condimentum. Vestibulum sollicitudin tellus a enim porttitor, quis euismod lectus pharetra. Praesent lacinia eget lorem at molestie. Praesent et mauris vitae lorem porta pretium. Aenean ac dictum justo. Integer sodales eros in libero fringilla venenatis. Curabitur convallis semper vehicula. Sed fermentum tempor arcu dapibus facilisis. Etiam ornare orci ullamcorper ipsum tristique aliquet. Quisque tellus felis, aliquam sed sapien vitae, ultrices auctor elit.

Donec commodo at nisi blandit pretium. Duis ornare metus eu felis suscipit, in fringilla dolor aliquet. Sed eleifend consectetur nibh eu.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-sm" style="background-color: yellow">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]